# Can't write on Samba4 share using Zentyal 6.1 server, after upgrading from 5, read only is allowed

Tags: samba, access-control-list, ext4, samba4, zentyal

I can't write on all my clients (Windows 7 and Windows 10) in all my samba shares, even if the users are accepted on domain, and the permissions was maintained. The shares are on a NAS, ISCSI connected. The line in my /etc/fstab is:

`UUID=98baebe4-ede3-4bed-a9e8-ff129f3988f4 /mnt/fileserver ext4 _netdev,user_xattr,acl,defaults 0 0`

Until I was on Zentyal 5 everything was OK. The error that the client gives is: "No authorization to execute the operation". Where's the Samba log for this?
I can read the files with all users. 
I tried to write with the domain admin, and no success.
I tried to write from ssh, using root, with success. So I believe is a restriction of Samba and not on Linux level (operating system).

Addition: I tried to set a share "guest allowed" from Zentyal interface, and then, I can write in a Windows 10 client...

Addition: I receive the following error:

`[2020/04/09 22:17:44.253864,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3139(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_create.c:293`

Answer (score 0):

Check the ACLs of the affected resources (as well as the folders that contain them). Make sure that there is no “mask” field restricting the correct permissions of users and groups and that the default ACLs of all folders are correct. For further info, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/6j6q8svdb/index.html